# Response Model Schema is coming as empty object in Swagger - C# | Swashbuckle

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

This is my API:

```
/// <summary>
        /// Gets activity logs.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="locationId">Location id.</param>
        /// <param name="filter">Activity log filter options.</param>
        [ResponseType(typeof(ActivityLogResponse))]
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> FetchActivityLogs(int locationId, ActivityLogFilterOptions filter)
        {
            try
            {
                var response = await _activityLogLogic.GetActivityLogs(CHIdentity.User, locationId, filter);
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, response);
            }
            catch (HttpRequestException ex)
            {
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex.Message + "\n" + ex.InnerException.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Defination of `ActivityLogResponse` class:

```
 public class ActivityLogResponse
    { 
       public List<ActivityLogMessage> ActivityLogs { get; set; }
       Logs { get; set; }
    }
```

In swagger JSON ***responses*** `"type": "object"` is coming instead of `ActivityLogFilterOptions`

See `Responses` in following Swagger Json:

```
    "/api/locations/{locationId}/FetchActivityLogs": {
        "post": {
            "tags": ["ActivityLog"],
            "summary": "Gets activity logs.",
            "operationId": "ActivityLog_FetchActivityLogs",
            "consumes": ["application/json", "text/json", "application/xml", "text/xml", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"],
            "produces": ["application/json", "text/json", "application/xml", "text/xml"],
            "parameters": [{
                    "name": "locationId",
                    "in": "path",
                    "description": "Location id.",
                    "required": true,
                    "type": "integer",
                    "format": "int32"
                }, {
                    "name": "filter",
                    "in": "body",
                    "description": "Activity log filter options.",
                    "required": true,
                    "schema": {
                        "$ref": "#/definitions/ActivityLogFilterOptions"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "responses": {
                "200": {
                    "description": "OK",
                    "schema": {
                        "type": "object"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

[image]

How to load `ActivityLogFilterOptions` here instead of `{}`?

Comment: That's strange. I just copied your method to a controller of mine (except the `CHAPIAuthorize` attribute and after fixing  `ActivityLogResponse` though) and it works perfectly fine. I also tried it with the `SwaggerResponse` attribute provide by `Swashbuckle` instead of the `ResponseType` attribute and that works alright too. Maybe you could try it with the `SwaggerResponse` attribute? Are you using a custom `IOperationFilter` to change the operationId?  Could it be that this filter messes with the response?

Comment: SwaggerResponse worked for me too. But I'm wondering why xml comments not working for me.. i also changed iOperationFilter acc. to this article https://mattfrear.com/2015/04/21/generating-swagger-example-responses-with-swashbuckle/ but didn't work.

Comment: i've also updated to latest version of swashbuckle